Webhook Sent 400 {"embeds": ["0"]}
getting a webhook error for this JSON when trying to post to discord:
{
    "content": "<@&1007047660735303700> <@&1142624156022747246>",
    "embeds": [
        {
            "title": "Bail Responses",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "**Arresting Officer's Full name**",
                    "value": "{{Arresting Officer's Full name}}"
                },
                {
                    "name": "**Arresting Officer's Email (Discord) Name**",
                    "value": "{{Arresting Officer's Email (Discord) Name}}"
                },
                {
                    "name": "**Defendant's Full name**",
                    "value": "{{Defendant's Full name}}"
                },
                {
                    "name": "**Defendants Email (Discord) Name**",
                    "value": "{{Defendants Email (Discord) Name}}"
                },
                {
                    "name": "**Defendant's Charges**",
                    "value": "{{Defendant's Charges}}"
                },
                {
                    "name": "**What is the report number?**",
                    "value": "{{What is the report number?}}"
                },
                {
                    "name": "**Does the Subject need public counsel?**",
                    "value": "{{Does the Subject need public councel?}}"
                },
                {
                    "name": "**Is the Subject jailed until trial?**",
                    "value": "{{Is the Subject jailed until trial?}}"
                },
                {
                    "name": "**Does the Subject want to Post Bond?**",
                    "value": "{{Does the Subject want to Post Bond?}}"
                },
                {
                    "name": "**If you fail to attend court on your scheduled date and no contact is made with your lawyer within 48 hours after the scheduled date the following will occur: - A warrant will be issued for Failure to Appear - Your Bail will be forfeited - You will not be eligible to go out on bail for the next 30 days. If you DO show up for your court date you may be eligible to receive a portion of your bond back minus 10% for DOJ Court Costs.**",
                    "value": "{{If you fail to attend court on your scheduled date and no contact is made with your lawyer within 48 hours after the scheduled date the following will occur: - A warrant will be issued for Failure to Appear - Your Bail will be forfeited - You will not be eligible to go out on bail for the next 30 days. If you DO show up for your court date you may be eligible to receive a portion of your bond back minus 10% for DOJ Court Costs.}}"
                },
                {
                    "name": "**What was the Total Amount Invoiced? (should be 2 times the fine)**",
                    "value": "{{What was the Total Amount Invoiced? (should be 2 times the fine)}}"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

it originally posted without any errors the first attempt, however when i copy and pasted the values to the names i forgot to remove the braces so it posted the values twice without the names, when i removed the braces i get "Webhook Sent 400 {"embeds": ["0"]}" error

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  It isn't clear what it is you're doing.  You've sent that to this api/webook; but what is it are you expecting it to return?  What are you actually doing?  How are you sending that?

trying to webhook a google form using an add-on

Discord has a character limit on embeds, and it is different to the usual plain message limit. A field name for example can only be up to 256 characters. Your second last field has 453 characters, causing it to return an error.

As the Discord docs state:
embeds is an array of embeds and can contain up to 10 embeds in the same message.

So you should split your fields in more messages. I was struggling with the same issue over here.
